# Sharing socket connections on multiple servers in Socket.io with Redis Store

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, redis, socket.io

I know that sharing rooms in `cluster` can be achieved by using the Redis store, however, can I share the rooms in a same way over multiple servers? So say I add socket user to room on server 1, can I send a broadcast a message to that room from the server 2, assuming I have connected to one Redis store during the socket.io setup?

Right now I am using the message queues to send messages to rooms, individually from each server and each server has own Redis store. So would sharing the store, also share the rooms across multiple servers?

Comment: I think it works fine. Just try and see.

Comment: @Xeos, I am making a chat application in which I need to keep tcp sockets of client at central store which could be accessed across multiple application server to deliver async message through message queue. I feel you also looked for similar. Let me know please if you got any. Thanks.

Comment: @ajay I ended up implementing it differently. Each Node.js server (process) is independent (no `cluster` used). They don't communicate with each other, but they use shared Redis instance to keep track of open sockets and who owns these sockets. Then, when a message is to be sent to the user (or socket_id), I look up the server that has open connections to the user in Redis and use Redis Pub/Sub to notify the responsible Node.js processes about the new message. It worked well so far. You can email me for more details.